# How to get AbpEntityChanges data for each row of the entity table?

Tags: abp

my application needs to show the entity change log for each row of the product table by clicking on a button in the row. But I don't know how to get the auditing data from the `abpEntityChanges` table.

the DTO I need for the frontend:

```
using System;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
using Volo.Abp.Auditing;

namespace App.Products
{
    public class EntityChangeDto : EntityDto<Guid> {
        
        public Guid AuditLogId {get; set;}
        public string EntityId {get; set;}
        public EntityChangeType ChangeType {get;set;}
        public DateTime ChangeTime {get; set;}
        public string UserName {get; set;}

    }
}
```

So I tried to make the IEntityChangeRepository first (derived from EntityChange class of the auditing module), and hoped to be able to use GetQueryableAsync in the AppService.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using Volo.Abp.AuditLogging;

namespace App.Products
{
    public interface IEntityChangeRepository : IRepository<EntityChange,Guid>
    {
        // need anything else here?
    }
}
```

an then added new task `GetEntityChangeListAsync` in my ProductAppService (of course also IProductAppService).

```
using System;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Dtos;
using Volo.Abp.Application.Services;
using Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Volo.Abp.AuditLogging;

namespace App.Products
{
    public class ProductAppService :
        CrudAppService<Product,ProductDto,Guid,GetProductListDto,CreateUpdateProductDto>,
        IProductAppService
    {
        private readonly IEntityChangeRepository _entityChangeRepository;
        private readonly IAuditLogRepository _auditLogRepository;

        public ProductAppService(
          IRepository<Product, Guid> repository
          IEntityChangeRepository entityChangeRepository,
          IAuditLogRepository auditLogRepository
        )
            : base(repository)
            {
                _entityChangeRepository = entityChangeRepository;
                _auditLogRepository = auditLogRepository;
            }
         
         public async Task<ListResultDto<EntityChangeDto>> GetEntityChangeListAsync(string id) {
            
             var queryable = await _entityChangeRepository.GetQueryableAsync();

             queryable = queryable
             .Where(p => p.EntityId.Equals(id))
             .OrderBy(p => p.ChangeTime);

             var query = from entityChange in queryable
                 join auditLog in _auditLogRepository on entityChange.AuditLogId equals auditLog.Id
                 select new { entityChange, auditLog };

             var queryResult = await AsyncExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

             var entityChangeDtos = queryResult.Select(x =>
                {
                    var entityChangeDto = ObjectMapper.Map<EntityChange,EntityChangeDto>(x.entityChange);
                    entityChangeDto.UserName = x.auditLog.UserName;
                    return entityChangeDto;
                }).ToList();
   
                return new ListResultDto<EntityChangeDto>(
                    entityChangeDtos
                );
            }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting error code 500. And I think the problem is most likely with the IEntityChangeRepository. Missing some mapping or the Repository is not queryable this way?
Could someone help please? many thanks ^^ I am beginner in the coding world but did my research in abp documents, couldnt solve it though :)

Error log

```
2021-03-25 07:59:20.505 +01:00 [ERR] An exception was thrown while activating Castle.Proxies.ProductAppServiceProxy.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Castle.Proxies.ProductAppServiceProxy.
 ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Volo.Abp.Autofac.AbpAutofacConstructorFinder' on type 'Castle.Proxies.ProductAppServiceProxy' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'App.Products.IEntityChangeRepository entityChangeRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[], Volo.Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`2[App.Products.Product,System.Guid], App.Products.IEntityChangeRepository, Volo.Abp.AuditLogging.IAuditLogRepository)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetAllBindings(ConstructorBinder[] availableConstructors, IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<ConfigurePipeline>b__11_0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<PropertiesAutowired>b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<OnPreparing>b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CoreEventMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ServiceBasedControllerActivator.Create(ControllerContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
2021-03-25 07:59:20.507 +01:00 [ERR] ---------- Exception Data ----------
ActivatorChain = Castle.Proxies.ProductAppServiceProxy
```

Comment: Do you have implementation of IEntityChangeRepository? It may be related with it. Also you can check the logs (under Logs/Logs.txt file) to see what the error is about. Add the error logs to your question please so, people can help better.

Comment: @gterdem thank you. Error logs added, please have a look. I don't have any other implementations of IEntityChangeRepository. Should I have? I thought LINK methods would be just available after `IEntityChangeRepository : IRepository<EntityChange,Guid>` (clearly i was wrong). sorry if the question is too stupid ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to find your way;

```
public class EfCoreAuditLogRepository : EfCoreRepository<IAuditLoggingDbContext, AuditLog, Guid>, IAuditLogRepository
    {
        public EfCoreAuditLogRepository(IDbContextProvider<IAuditLoggingDbContext> dbContextProvider)
            : base(dbContextProvider)
        {

        }

        public override async Task<IQueryable<AuditLog>> WithDetailsAsync()
        {
            return (await GetQueryableAsync()).IncludeDetails();
        }

        public virtual async Task<EntityChange> GetEntityChange(
            Guid entityChangeId,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var entityChange = await (await GetDbContextAsync()).Set<EntityChange>()
                                    .AsNoTracking()
                                    .IncludeDetails()
                                    .Where(x => x.Id == entityChangeId)
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(GetCancellationToken(cancellationToken));

            if (entityChange == null)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException(typeof(EntityChange));
            }

            return entityChange;
        }

        public virtual async Task<List<EntityChange>> GetEntityChangeListAsync(
            string sorting = null,
            int maxResultCount = 50,
            int skipCount = 0,
            Guid? auditLogId = null,
            DateTime? startTime = null,
            DateTime? endTime = null,
            EntityChangeType? changeType = null,
            string entityId = null,
            string entityTypeFullName = null,
            bool includeDetails = false,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var query = await GetEntityChangeListQueryAsync(auditLogId, startTime, endTime, changeType, entityId, entityTypeFullName, includeDetails);

            return await query.OrderBy(sorting.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? (nameof(EntityChange.ChangeTime) + " DESC") : sorting)
                .PageBy(skipCount, maxResultCount)
                .ToListAsync(GetCancellationToken(cancellationToken));
        }

        public virtual async Task<long> GetEntityChangeCountAsync(
            Guid? auditLogId = null,
            DateTime? startTime = null,
            DateTime? endTime = null,
            EntityChangeType? changeType = null,
            string entityId = null,
            string entityTypeFullName = null,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var query = await GetEntityChangeListQueryAsync(auditLogId, startTime, endTime, changeType, entityId, entityTypeFullName);

            var totalCount = await query.LongCountAsync(GetCancellationToken(cancellationToken));

            return totalCount;
        }

        public virtual async Task<EntityChangeWithUsername> GetEntityChangeWithUsernameAsync(
            Guid entityChangeId,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var auditLog = await (await GetDbSetAsync()).AsNoTracking().IncludeDetails()
                .Where(x => x.EntityChanges.Any(y => y.Id == entityChangeId)).FirstAsync(GetCancellationToken(cancellationToken));

            return new EntityChangeWithUsername()
            {
                EntityChange = auditLog.EntityChanges.First(x => x.Id == entityChangeId),
                UserName = auditLog.UserName
            };
        }

        protected virtual async Task<IQueryable<EntityChange>> GetEntityChangeListQueryAsync(
            Guid? auditLogId = null,
            DateTime? startTime = null,
            DateTime? endTime = null,
            EntityChangeType? changeType = null,
            string entityId = null,
            string entityTypeFullName = null,
            bool includeDetails = false)
        {
            return (await GetDbContextAsync())
                .Set<EntityChange>()
                .AsNoTracking()
                .IncludeDetails(includeDetails)
                .WhereIf(auditLogId.HasValue, e => e.AuditLogId == auditLogId)
                .WhereIf(startTime.HasValue, e => e.ChangeTime >= startTime)
                .WhereIf(endTime.HasValue, e => e.ChangeTime <= endTime)
                .WhereIf(changeType.HasValue, e => e.ChangeType == changeType)
                .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityId), e => e.EntityId == entityId)
                .WhereIf(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityTypeFullName), e => e.EntityTypeFullName.Contains(entityTypeFullName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Alper. Inspired by your comment, I just realized that I could use the `GetEntityChangesWithUsernameAsync` method of `EfCoreAuditLogRepository` from AuditLogging module directly in my AppService. Works like a charm. :)